# How to use row_number() in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have received error when running the code below - below is an example for your reference.

BRDB.EXPORT SHIPMENT (database table)

```
 SHPMNT_REF  | SHIPMENT_TYPE
    123      | EHO
    456      | EHO
    789      | EHO
```

BRDB.EVENT_CODE (database table)

```
 FILE_NO  | REMARKS   EVENT_CODE
 123      | TEST0      SIR
 123      | TEST1      SIR
 123      | TEST2      SIR
 456      | TEST3      SIR
 789      | TEST4      EEO
```

What I want to show in report is like

```
  FILE NO    |  REMARKS
     123     |  TEST0,TEST1,TEST2
     456     |  TEST3
```

Below is my coding

```
select min(X.SHPMNT_REF) as "House B/L #",
       listagg(case when SIR = 1 then X.REMARKS end, ',') within group (order by X.SHPMNT_REF) as "REMARKS(from SIR Event)"
FROM   (select ES.SHPMNT_REF,
               (select EE.REMARKS,
                       row_number() over (order by EE.FILE_NO)
                FROM   BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT EE
                where  EE.FILE_NO = ES.SHPMNT_REF
                and    EE.EVENT_CODE = 'SIR') as SIR
        from   BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES)X
GROUP BY X.SHPMNT_REF
```

The following is the error i received.

```
Multiple columns are returned from a subquery that is allowed only one column.. SQLCODE=-412, SQLSTATE=42823, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-412", SQLSTATE "42823" and message tokens "".
```

Comment: The `row_number()` itself isn't the problem; as the error says, you have a subquery that's getting multiple columns - `(select EE.REMARKS,row_number() ...)` - in a place that it only makes sense to get one column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the idea that you want:

```
select ec.file_no,
       listagg(ec.remarks, ',') within group (order by ec.remarks) remarks
from event_code ec
where (ec.file_no, ec.event_code) not in
           (select SHPMNT_REF, SHIPMENT_TYPE
            from BRDB.EXPORT SHIPMENT
           )
      )
group by ec.file_no;
```

I don't see what `row_number()` has to do with your specified results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Actually I cant group by ec.file_no since BRDB.EXPORT SHIPMENT will be my main table and there is a lot of data from there. Do you have any others way so solve this?

Comment: Please asst again since this is really urgent for me. Thanks.

Comment: @CKAng . . . I think you may need to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select EE.REMARKS,
row_number() over (order by EE.FILE_NO) 
FROM BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT EE where EE.FILE_NO = ES.SHPMNT_REF 
                            and EE.EVENT_CODE = 'SIR'
) as Sir
```

this upper query is returned multiple column but you used alias `Sir` which is incorrect so it returned error

you can use join to replce subquery

```
select 
min(X.SHPMNT_REF) as "House B/L #",

listagg(case when SIR = 1 then X.REMARKS
end, ',') within group (order by X.SHPMNT_REF) as "REMARKS(from SIR Event)"

FROM
(select
ES.SHPMNT_REF,

row_number() over (order by EE.FILE_NO)  
  as SIR

from BRDB.EXPORT_SHIPMENT ES join BRDB.EXPORT_EVENT EE
on EE.FILE_NO = ES.SHPMNT_REF where EE.EVENT_CODE = 'SIR'
)X
GROUP BY X.SHPMNT_REF
```

Comment: Hi, the coding you provided is not showing what I want.